# Как работает html тэг img с политикой cors?

Tags: javascript, img, cors

Объясните максимально подробно. К примеру, у нас есть сервер без cors заголовков. Если мы попытаемся сделать **простой** **cors** **get** запрос на получение изображения для дальнейшей работы с ним в бинарном виде, то наш **body** будет пустым, так как **content-type** по спецификации не может быть, к примеру, **image/png**.
Собственно, вопрос: как в этом плане тэг img получает данные в атрибуте src и отображает изображение?

p.s. поправьте где не прав

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Основная задача CORS - запрет получения результата запроса с вашего сайта на другой, используя его куки.
Без него, вы бы, скажем, могли бы читать мои личные сообщения в vk(пока я в нём залогинен), если бы я зашёл на ваш сайт)

С картинками эта проблема тоже присутствует.
Теоретически, вы могли бы выкачать через свой сайт фото из моего закрытого альбома, только придётся подобрать точные URI =)

Но отображать чужие картинки нужно(не заставлять же всех всё хранить у себя), поэтому придумали другое решение.
Единственная возможность получить данные с картинки - предварительно скопировать его на canvas. Если при этом сервер не предоставил CORS разрешений, при любой попытке прочитать данные с этого «испорченного» canvas вы получите SecurityError.

> Собственно, вопрос: как в этом плане тэг img получает данные в
> атрибуте src и отображает изображение?

Берёт, получает и отображает. Политики безопасности применяются только к попыткам пользоватьских скриптов получить данные с картинки. Можно провести аналогию с iframe — показать можно, что-то сделать внутри нельзя.

Comment: Вы пишите очевидное. Не вижу ответа на вопрос. при чём тут canvas вообще ?

Comment: Как при чём? А как вы данные с картинки собираетесь считывать?

Comment: К примеру если cors заголовок Access-Control-Allow-Origin со значением "*", то мы можем послать через fetch get запрос на изображение с Content-type: image/png, получить данные и работать с ними как с бинарником

Comment: ок, а при чём тут тег img?

Comment: ну я изначально про это спрашивал :) Если коротко, то почему тэг img может загрузить и отобразить данные, а если делать xhr, то данных мы не увидим. При условии что в cors заголовках нету нашего домена

Comment: В том и ответ. Вы и в img доступ к данным не получите. А то, что картинка отображается - не проблема, пользователь к её просмотру авторизован.

Comment: что вы подразумеваете под словом авторизован?

Comment: [авторизован](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Авторизация) - допущен к ресурсу. Если он может посмотреть картинку на оригинальном сайте - значит прав хватает.